# Query was empty error?

Tags: php

got a Query was empty error with this code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(cpp) FROM carbsummary"); 
$row = mysql_query($result); 

if($result === FALSE) { die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
    }
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
    echo $row['value_sum'];
    }
```

I have been digging around and there are a lot of ways in which this error can occur but I just cant seem to see it.

Comment: `$row` is a query on a query, that's incorrect

Comment: you're trying to do a query with the result of other query...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(cpp) as value_sum FROM carbsummary"); 
// $row = mysql_query($result); // There is no need for this second 'mysql_query'

if ($result === FALSE) { die(mysql_error()); }
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo $row['value_sum'];
}
```

First, that second `mysql_query` is completely unneeded. Also, I added `as value_sum` to your query so your `echo $row['value_sum'];` can actually work.

Past that, when you say this:

> I have been digging around and there are alot of ways in which this
>   error can occur but I just can't seem to see it.

I can’t believe you are serious. You are showing less than 10 lines of code with a profoundly simply MySQL query. Simply looking at [the official PHP documentation for `mysql_query`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) shows lots of useful examples you can copy & adjust for your needs. Within 10 minutes of copying, pasting & adjusting your code would be ready to go.

Additionally, you are using `mysql_` extensions when `mysqli_` extensions are the way to go. Click on that link again and read the giant red box at the top of the page:

> **Warning** This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)
>   extension should be used. See also [MySQL: choosing an API](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) guide
>   and [related FAQ](https://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated) for more information. Alternatives to this
>   function include:
>
> - [mysqli_query()](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)
> - [PDO::query()](https://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php)

Comment: In regards to the answer you gave it has helped as i have no errors so thank you for that.